# How change item of listview or recyclerview dynamically?

Tags: android

How to change speciafy items background twinklally in listview or recyclerview? I haven't found dispatch event to childview method in listview or recyclerview. so I trying update items background use thread and handler in viewholder. have someone fixed the problem? long time I seached the anwser. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For ListView use - `notifydatasetchanged();`

For RecyclerView you can use `notifydatasetchanged()` or  `notifyItemChanged(position);`

but `notifyItemChanged` will only notify the item at the given position.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update some item in RecyclerView - call notifyItemChanged(position) method of RecyclerView.Adapter and change view as you want.

notifydatasetchanged() - for listview